# "invalid use of incomplete type ‘class tree_node_t’" when inheriting class

Tags: c++

**node.h:**

```
#include "tree_node.h"

class tree_node_t;
class node_base : public tree_node_t
{
public:
    node_base();
    ~node_base();
};
```

**tree_node.h:**

```
#include "node.h"

class node_base;
class tree_node_t
{
    tree_node_t();

    std::vector<node_base*> list;
    . . .
}
```

Everything looks seems to be correct, but for some reason I get the error "invalid use of incomplete type ‘class tree_node_t’". I don't understand why this is happening.

As far as I understand, the solution to these problems is to split the files into headers (.h) and source code files (.cpp). Divided, but continue to receive such a mistake.

Comment: You cannot use an incomplete type for deriving from it. A forward declaration provide an incomplete type and that is why it does not work ;).

However, your forward declration for your vector is good ;)

Comment: Remove the include from the second file.

Comment: Most likely you want the `tree_node_t` to inherit from `node_base` (because why would you wan't that ?). Can you elaborate on what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: What @Markus said: simply removing the `#include` from `tree_node.h` should solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[natersoz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/138264/natersoz) and [Markus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2790838/markus) was right. All I had to do was remove `#include` from `tree_node.h`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't inherit from an incomplete type. The compiler needs to have the full definition of `tree_node_t` when inheriting from it in order to correctly determine the size of the class as well as the offset of the data members.

But by putting `class tree_node_t;` after already having included the header you shadow the definition that the compiler needs. So just removing the line `class tree_node_t;` should make everyting compile fine, unless you're also missing [include guards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard).

As correctly pointed out by [Rudolfs Bundulis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1458617/rudolfs-bundulis) you also need to remove the `#include "node.h"` in `tree_node.h` because otherwise the code that gets passed to the compiler when including `tree_node.h` looks like this:

```
class node_base : public tree_node_t
{
public:
  node_base();
  ~node_base();
 };

 class node_base;
 class tree_node_t
 {
   tree_node_t();

   std::vector<node_base*> list;
   . . .
 };
```

which can't compile because suddendly the definition of `tree_node_t` comes after the definition of `node_base` which tries to inherit from it.

Comment: How could it compile fine if the files are recursively including each other?

Comment: @Rudolfs Bundulis I (incorrectly?) assumed there also are include guards.

Comment: It sounds plausible, but now I'm getting a new error: `expected class-name before ‘{’ token`. What I should do?

Comment: @garbart If what you posted as content of `tree_node.h` is indeed everything inside that file then you're missing the `#include <vector>` and you're missing a semicolon after the definition of `tree_node_t`.

Comment: @Corristo well, that is not a correct statement in this case. He would be safe when he does `#include "node.h"` but not when he does `#include "tree_node.h"`, since it will cause recursion.

Comment: Perhaps, the most correct decision will be to use templates for tree_node? 

The code inside the tree_node is too large to be laid out in its entirety. `vector` is already included.

Comment: @garbart yes, templates would be better, since as I mentioned above, there is still a possible recursion depending on which header you include, and honestly, I don't see why you wan't `node_base` to inherit from `tree_node_t`. If you will want other types as well, templating the class makes more sense.

Comment: @RudolfsBundulis With include guards there is no infinite recursion, as the second time around the `#include "tree_node.h"` won't be executed by the preprocessor again.

Comment: @garbart I suggest to get it working for a fixed type of values first and then later try to convert it into a template. But whatever compiler error you still get is not due to the code you posted, as you can see in this [wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/u2Jd93vtSac9Jf4L) where everything compiles just fine.

Comment: @Corristo - ok, I did not make myself clear. The dependencies are recursive, not the includes themselves. Just try it yourself, take the wandbox link, and change the main to `#include "tree_node.h"

int main() {
    return 0;
}`

Comment: @RudolfsBundulis You're right, I've missed that. I've corrected the answer.

Comment: I was initially going to downvote, but you actually showed that I did not make myself clear about the recursion. As I said, this is more of a design problem.

Comment: @garbart Rudolfs Bundulis' remark also expained your error `expected class-name before ‘{’ token`. I've improved the answer.

Answer (score 0):

> As far as I understand, the solution to these problems is to split the
>   files into headers (.h) and source code files (.cpp).

Splitting the code into files is often the preferred solution.  It is at least something good for you to practice.

Generally, however, one can still do this code in a single file, and in this case with one forward declaration.

The following compiles, links, and runs (but does very little):

---

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout, std::flush, std::endl;

#include <vector>
using std::vector;

// in this ordering, the single forward suffices,
//   because all class pointers are a known size,
// and
//    this symbol (as yet) is only in the tree_node_t data, 
//    in the vector as a pointer

class node_base_t;


class tree_node_t
{
   // private data attributes
   vector<node_base_t*> list;

   // tbd ... other data

public:
   tree_node_t()  // default ctor
   // : list ctor is ok
      {
         cout << "\n  tree_node_t() " << flush;
      }

   ~tree_node_t() = default; // dtor

   // tbd ... more public functions

private:
   // tbd ... private functions
};


class node_base_t : public tree_node_t
{
   // private data
   // ... tbd - other data
public:
   node_base_t()  // tree_node_t default ctor is ok
      {
         cout << "\n  node_base_t() " << flush;
      }

    ~node_base_t() = default;

   // tbd ... more public functions
private:
   // tbd ... private functions
};

int main(int , char** )
{
   int retVal = -1;
   {
      node_base_t  nb;

      retVal = 0;
   }
   cout << "\n" << endl;

   return retVal;
}
```

output:

```
  tree_node_t() 
  node_base_t()
```

Comment: I hope it is clear that any tree_node_t function that invokes a node_base_t function, must be (a) declared in tree_node_t and (b) implemented after the node_base_t declarations.